# List size greater than 0 with all null items in list

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

I'm seeing some weird behaviour in my code:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at java.util.ArrayList.clear(ArrayList.java:453) ~[na:1.6.0_35]
```

I'm calling `frcSegmentWeights.clear()` and `frcSegmentWeights` has size of 11 and containing only null items.

I'm guessing ArrayList keeps an buffer somewhere internally, and the list gets cleared in a previous iteration, hence the nulls. Next, the buffer `size()` gets copied and when the next `clear()` is called, the exception is thrown. How can I synchronize this?

Comment: Is this multi-threaded?

Comment: It runs in a OSGI framework, but I have no Ideea in which order the threads are dispatched. The code is the list.clear(), this should be pretty self-explanatory.. Nothing too complex, only that the size() and the actual elements present inside do not coincide.

Comment: @MihaiGALOS: Tim is implicitly asking whether you have any synchronisation that prevents simultaneous read/write access to the list.

Comment: No, no synchronization. Bad, huh?